If $A\subseteq\{0,1,2,...,2024\}$, $S=\{a+b:a,b\in A\}$, $T=\{|a-b|:a,b\in A\}$, and $T\bigcap S=\varnothing$, then at most how big is $A$?

We assume that the set $A\subseteq\{0,1,2,...,2024\}$, let $S=\{a+b:a,b\in A\}$, $T=\{|a-b|:a,b\in A\}$, and $T\bigcap S=\varnothing$. How many elements can there be in the set $A$ at most?

I guess the answer is $1350$, when $A=\{675,676,...,2024\}$.
But I don't know how to solve this problem; even the answer I guessed is wrong.
Can anyone provide me an idea?

How do you know it's wrong??

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070277/no-sum-of-three-numbers-equals-another-number-in-set?rq=1
